# Хочу, чтобы шар двигался не только влево и вправо, а и вверх и вниз

Tags: python, tkinter, idle

Хочу,чтобы красный шар двигался не только влево и вправо,а и вверх и  вниз

```
import tkinter as t
import random

root = t.Tk()
root['bg'] = 'grey'

x = 400
y = 300
dx = 5

canvas = t.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600, bg='lightblue')
canvas.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

oval = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+50, y+50, fill='red', outline='red')

def roll():
    global x, y, dx, oval
    x = x + dx
    if x < 0 or x > 750:
        dx = -dx
    canvas.coords(oval, x, y, x+50, y+50)
    root.after(20, roll)

roll()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Опишите более подробно, что Вы хотите. По какой траектории должен двигаться?

Comment: Ну когда он вправо и влево движения сделал,то  когда он доходит до середины,он должен двигатся вверх и вниз,потом опять дошёл до середины и опять вправо и влево

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глуповато конечно сделано, но как то так

```
import tkinter as t


def roll():
    global x, y, dx, oval, a
    if a:
        x = x + dx
        if x < 0 or x > 750:
            dx = -dx
        elif x == 400 and dx == 5:
            a = False
    else:
        y = y + dx
        if y < 0 or y > 550:
            dx = -dx
        elif y == 300 and dx == 5:
            a = True

    canvas.coords(oval, x, y, x+50, y+50)
    root.after(20, roll)


root = t.Tk()
root['bg'] = 'grey'

x = 400
y = 300
dx = 5
a = True
canvas = t.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600, bg='lightblue')
canvas.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

oval = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+50, y+50, fill='red', outline='red')

roll()

root.mainloop()
```